# How to split an akka ByteString at a two byte delimiter

Tags: websocket, akka

I'm creating a WebSocket protocol of my own, and thought to have a text key/value header part, ending at two consecutive newlines, followed by a binary tail.

Turns out, splitting a `ByteString` in half (at the two newlines) is really tedious. There is no built-in `.split` method, for one. And no `.indexOf` for finding a binary fingerprint.

What would you use for this? Is there an easier way for me to build such a protocol?

References:

- akka [ByteString](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.8/akka/util/ByteString.html)

Using akka-http 10.1.0-RC1, akka 2.5.8

Comment: There's an (internal) streaming LineParser in the akka-http source code that you could copy / reuse. See https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/86c56ab41c595b739f36b30bbf3135cdb7e45bba/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/unmarshalling/sse/LineParser.scala#L25

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to first create sliding pairs from an indexedSeq of the ByteString, then split the ByteString using the identified indexes of the delimiter-pair, as in the following example:

```
import akka.util.ByteString

val bs = ByteString("aa\nbb\n\nxyz")
// bs: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(97, 97, 10, 98, 98, 10, 10, 120, 121, 122)

val delimiter = 10

// Create sliding pairs from indexedSeq of the ByteString
val slidingList = bs.zipWithIndex.sliding(2).toList
// slidingList: List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Byte, Int)]] = List(
//   Vector((97,0), (97,1)), Vector((97,1), (10,2)), Vector((10,2), (98,3)),
//   Vector((98,3), (98,4)), Vector((98,4), (10,5)), Vector((10,5), (10,6)),
//   Vector((10,6), (120,7)), Vector((120,7), (121,8)), Vector((121,8), (122,9))
// )

// Get indexes of the delimiter-pair
val dIndex = slidingList.filter{
  case Vector(x, y) => x._1 == delimiter && y._1 == delimiter
}.flatMap{
  case Vector(x, y) => Seq(x._2, y._2)
}

// Split the ByteString list
val (bs1, bs2) = ( bs.splitAt(dIndex(0))._1, bs.splitAt(dIndex(1))._2.tail )
// bs1: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(97, 97, 10, 98, 98)
// bs2: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(120, 121, 122)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. Haven't tested it in practise, yet.

```
@tailrec
def peelMsg(bs: ByteString, accHeaderLines: Seq[String]): Tuple2[Seq[String],ByteString] = {

  val (a: ByteString, tail: ByteString) = bs.span(_ != '\n')
  val b: ByteString = tail.drop(1)

  if (a.isEmpty) {    // end marker - empty line
    Tuple2(accHeaderLines,b)
  } else {
    val acc: Seq[String] = accHeaderLines :+ a.utf8String    // append
    peelMsg(b,acc)
  }
}

val (headerLines: Seq[String], value: ByteString) = peelMsg(bs,Seq.empty)
```

Comment: Don't use this. It's not necessary to go recursive; better ideas seem to be around, but I'm leaving it here for the sake of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

My code, for now:

```
// Find the index of the (first) double-newline
//
val n: Int = {
  val bsLen: Int = bs.length

  val tmp: Int = bs.zipWithIndex.find{
    case ('\n',i) if i<bsLen-1 && bs(i+1)=='\n' => true
    case _ => false
  }.map(_._2).getOrElse{
    throw new RuntimeException("No delimiter found")
  }
  tmp
}

val (bs1: ByteString, bs2: ByteString) = bs.splitAt(n)    // headers, \n\n<binary>
```

Influenced by @leo-c's answer, but using a normal `.find` instead of the sliding window. Realised that since `ByteString` allows random access, I can combine a streaming search with that condition.